# How to remove a CCombo from a Table in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I added a `CCombo` to a column of a table item:

```
TableEditor ceditor = new TableEditor(table);
...
ceditor.setEditor(combo, item, columnIndex);
```

In the ... part I added a `SelectionListener` and so on.

I added the functionality of removing table items. If you do so, the `CCombo` remains on the Table and is not connected to any item (so if you click on it the program crashes). How can I remove the `CCombo` of this column?

Comment: Please provide a stand-alone example and show us the stack trace.

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before removing the table column, you should remove the corresponding table editor with `tableEditor.dispose()`.

Disposing of the table editor leaves the combo intact. Hence you need to hide the combo if you plan to reuse it with another column/table editor or also dispose of it entirely.